# gsub is missing to add string between two commas

Tags: r, pattern-matching, gsub

I have the following string:

```
a <- "2015,,,,6GR,09,PRIVATE,NP,001"
```

I would like to add "YES" between each comma. So I'd like to have the following output:

```
"2015,YES,YES,YES,6GR,09,PRIVATE,NP,001"
```

I tried the following line:

```
gsub("([,])([,])", "\\1YES\\2", a)
```

But my output is:

```
"2015,YES,,YES,6GR,09,PRIVATE,NP,001"
```

Can someone tell me why gsub is missing the two commmas in the middle and how I can solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use positive [look-ahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) :

```
gsub(",(?=,)",",YES",a,perl=TRUE)
# [1] "2015,YES,YES,YES,6GR,09,PRIVATE,NP,001"
```

or alternatively a positive [look-behind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) :

```
gsub("(?<=,),","YES,",a,perl=TRUE)
# [1] "2015,YES,YES,YES,6GR,09,PRIVATE,NP,001"
```

The problem with your approach is that your regular expression "consumes" the first two consecutive comma and considers that a match, then proceeds with the next consecutive two commas, missing the match in the middle.

Instead, characters in look-ahead and look-behind parts (i.e. `(?=,)` and `(?<=,)`) are not actually "consumed" by the regular expressions, hence it works.

The `perl=TRUE` enable the regular-expression flavour that supports the look-around feature.

Comment: I tried perl=T in my code thinking it will fix.  I didn't know positive-look-ahead, thanks a lot.

Comment: @kukushkin: perl=TRUE won't fix your regex, it is only necessary to support "look-arounds" feature in gsub regex. Added a brief explanation

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to solve it for you in a different matter instead of trying to answer your problem, which I can't.

Just do it:

```
a= unlist(strsplit(a,","))
a[a==""]="YES"
a=paste(a,collapse=",")
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that after matching `,,` the second comma is not re-scanned.  Try this instead where `"\\B"` matches a non-word-boundary to avoid having to match the second comma.  This should work as long as you don't have fields that start with non-word characters such as `"A,,,;B"`.  It also won't work for the first and last fields but the expression in the question did not work for those either so we assume that this is not a problem.

```
gsub(",\\B", ",YES", a)
## [1] "2015,YES,YES,YES,6GR,09,PRIVATE,NP,001"
```